Chern clasess and the Hartshorne Serre Correspondence for Rank 2 Vector Bundles
Recall the Hartshorne-Serre correspondence for rank $2$ vector bundles on a smooth algebraic surface $X$
Hartshorne-Serre Correspondence. If $Z$ is a zero dimensional closed subscheme of $X$, and $|L'^{-1}+L+K_X|$ satisfies the Cayley-Bacharach property w.r.t $Z$, then there exists a rank $2$ vector bundle $E$ sitting in the exact sequence $0\to L\to E\to L'\otimes I_Z\to 0$.
Here, the Cayley-Bacharach property states that if a divisor $D$ in the linear system passes through all but one point of $Z$, then it must pass through that last point. One can get that such an exact sequence exists for any rank $2$ vector bundle by twisting $E$ by an ample line bundle enough times and then considering the Koszul complex associated to a section.
Question. How much does $Z$ determine $E$? Let's make this question easier and take $L=O_X$ and $L'=O_X$ and look at $0\to O_X\to E\to O_X\otimes I_Z\to 0$. Clearly, $c_1(E)=O_X$ and $c_2(E)=c_2(I_Z)$. So at the very least $c_2(I_Z)$ is an invariant and so if $0\to O_X\to E\to O_X\otimes I_{Z'}\to 0$ is another exact sequence $E$ sits in, then $c_2(I_Z)=c_2(I_{Z'})$. But this implies $[Z]=[Z']$ in $\operatorname{CH}^2(X)$.
Is it perhaps possible that whenever $Z$ is rationally equivalent to $Z'$, then there is an exact sequence using $I_{Z'}$ instead?

Let me assume that $X$ is proper and connected. Then the cohomology exact sequence of
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to E \to I_Z \to 0
$$
shows that $H^0(E) = k$ (the base field), hence $E$ has a unique (up to rescaling) global section, and the above sequence implies that $Z$ is the zero locus of this section. Thus, you can reconstruct $Z$ from $E$.

So basically, for any proper connected smooth $X$, there are as many / far more nonisomorphic rank $2$ vector bundles as there are zero dimensional subschemes of $X$? That's pretty neat!
